# Classification of topologically constrained foliations on $X$ in low dimensions i.e. $2,3$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Take $X=(0,1)^n.$ Fix points $p,q$ s.t. $\text{dist}_n(p,q)=\sqrt{n}.$

> Problem: Classify analytic regular foliations of $X$ with $(n-1)-$dim. leaves which are topologically $(0,\sqrt{n})\times S^{n-2} $ accumulating to $p,q.$

The problem is trivial until dim. $2,$ and I have found one (real analytic foliation) solution in $n=2$ dim. but have not completely classified for $n=2.$

I conjecture that there are no solutions for $n\gt2$ and I would be shocked if there was a solution.

My solution for $n=2$:

Foliation $F_s=\big\{\log x \log y=s: s\in (0,\infty) \big\}$ which satisfies $\cup_s F_s=X,$ is clearly analytic and regular, and satisfies the topological constraint as well as the accumulation criterion. In this case, note that $p=(0,1)$ and $q=(1,0).$

I feel like there should be a more elegant approach here. My solution does not let one see the global classification picture and is only an isolated example that happens to work.

Perhaps the problem is easier in the complex setting.

Edit 3/19/2023:

I will relax the conditions. Let $n=3.$

Take $X=(0,1)^n.$ Fix points $p,q$ s.t. $\text{dist}_n(p,q)=\sqrt{n}.$ Construct a smooth regular foliation of $X$ with $(n-1)-$dim. leaves which are topologically $(0,\sqrt{n})\times S^{n-2} $ accumulating to $p,q.$

I think this is a much more tractable problem. I am only looking for a construction in dimension $3$ now, where I've replaced "analytic" with "smooth."

I am including the following related question I posted $10$ months ago (link below), because it is an attempt at a solution (in the smooth case) for any dimension $n.$ This method leverages distribution theory and imagines the leaves as arising from integrating some continuous bivariate probability distribution. In this way a single leaf is precisely the distribution when all the parameters are fixed. What's interesting about this method is that you get the topological condition for sufficient constraints on the probability distribution.

Since the definition in the linked post below includes $p,q$ in the leafs, then deleting $p,q$ would match up with my definition in this post.

[Understanding a subspace of $S^n$ for a given distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4448450/understanding-a-subspace-of-sn-for-a-given-distribution).

Comment: Your edited question is equivalent to the existence of a smooth foliation of $\mathbb R^3$ whose leaves are all diffeomorphic to the open annulus $(0,1) \times S^1$. I tried a literature search and while I did not come up with an answer, [this paper by  Inaba and Masuda](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.03837.pdf) is interesting in that it describes a certain class of connected surfaces $S$ such that $\mathbb R^3$ does have a smooth foliation by leaves all diffeomorphic to $S$.

Comment: The class they describe (on page 14) includes $S = \mathbb R^2 - (\mathbb Z \times \{0\})$, and it includes $S = \mathbb R^2 - (C \times \{0\})$ where $C$ is the Cantor set. Unfortunately it does not include $S = \mathbb R^2 - \text{($1$ point)}$ which is (diffeomorphic to) the open annulus.

Comment: I don't know if it matters but, I was thinking of changing the definition and consider deleting the longest diagonal in $X$ for $n>2$ because from my understanding for $n=3$, you get a singular 1 dimensional leaf i.e. the surfaces foliating $(0,1)^3$ collapse at some point to this 1 dim. singular leaf making the foliation not technically regular...please correct me if I'm wrong on this.

Comment: There certainly do exist singular foliations of the kind you have just described. Nonetheless, the question of whether there exist nonsingular foliations of the kind asked in your post remains interesting.

Comment: @LeeMosher In your first 2 comments, do the punctured planes all have to share the same punctured point? Is this the foliation of R^3 you are describing?

Comment: I do not understand your last comment. I can only reword what I have already written: my second comment describes certain explicit open subsets $S \subset \mathbb R^2$; the paper of Inaba and Masuda is about foliations of $\mathbb R^3$ whose leaves are all diffeomorphic to $S$. Their proof is complicated; I cannot describe those foliations.

Comment: Okay - @LeeMosher do you have any idea of a solution?

Comment: I do not, that's why my comments are merely comments.

Comment: Doesn't a foliation of a class $S=\Bbb R^2$ minus 1 point simply foliate $\Bbb R^3$ minus a line? So in your first comment shouldn't you say "foliation of $\Bbb R^3$ minus a line" ? as opposed to foliation of $\Bbb R^3$

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but it's trivial to foliate $\Bbb R^3$ minus a line with the class $S=\Bbb R^2$ minus a point, in a non singular manner..

Comment: It certainly is trivial. But $\mathbb R^3$ minus a line is not diffeomorphic to the space $(0,1)^3$ which you asked to foliate in your original post.

Comment: But surely one needs $(0,1)^3$ **minus a longest diagonal** right? because due to the topological condition and accumulating property I see absolutely no way for such a class of cylinders accumulating to $p,q$ to foliate the entirety of $(0,1)^3$ without being singular

Comment: A couple of things. First, of course $(0,1)^3$ minus the longest diagonal can be foliated in that manner. And I also see absolutely no way to foliate $(0,1)^3$ by once-punctured planes without singularities. But my inability to see it does not mean it doesn't exist, and I do not know whether such a foliation does or does not exist. That's one reason I find your post so interesting; another reason is what I said in my very first comment, there are even weirder surfaces than a once punctured plane which ***do*** foliate $(0,1)^3$ without any singularities whatsoever.